# Electron with Vue disable auto reload

Tags: vue.js, electron, reload

I install Electron with Vue using this [tutorial](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-electron/).

I looking for answer how I can disable auto reload ?
I start my application using `npm run dev`, when I change somethink in code Electron run auto reload (refreshes and compiles the application again
). I would like to refresh the application myself after writing a part of the code.
I don't use `Webpack`.

Yes, I know I can disable auto save in Visual Studio Code, but this is not a solution.

Comment: If you're following that specific tutorial, you **are** using Webpack, because the template it refers to "simulatedgreg/electron-vue" uses Webpack: [SimulatedGREG/electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/tree/master/template/.electron-vue).

Answer (score 0):

#### Disable on Main and Renderer processes

Remove the call of `startElectron()` in `dev-runner.js > startMain()`.

```
function startMain () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mainConfig.entry.main = [path.join(__dirname, '../src/main/index.dev.js')].concat(mainConfig.entry.main)
    mainConfig.mode = 'development'
    const compiler = webpack(mainConfig)

    compiler.hooks.watchRun.tapAsync('watch-run', (compilation, done) => {
      //Remove these lines and ...
      // logStats('Main', chalk.white.bold('compiling...'))
      // hotMiddleware.publish({ action: 'compiling' })
      done()
    })

    compiler.watch({}, (err, stats) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return
      }

      //... these lines.
      // logStats('Main', stats)
      //
      // if (electronProcess && electronProcess.kill) {
      //   manualRestart = true
      //   process.kill(electronProcess.pid)
      //   electronProcess = null
      //   startElectron()
      //
      //   setTimeout(() => {
      //     manualRestart = false
      //   }, 5000)
      // }

      resolve()
    })
  })
}
```

#### Disable only on Renderer process

Delete import line below from `src/main/index.js`.

```
import '../renderer/store';
```

This line is required by [vuex-electron](https://github.com/vue-electron/vuex-electron) which makes vuex to run on main process. If you are not planning to use `createPersistedState()` or `createSharedMutations()`, you can delete this.

Comment: @michal is not using webpack

Comment: @tpikachu [simulatedgreg/electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) sets up webpack automatically. If you have typed `npm run dev` as shown in the tutorial, you are using webpack.